# Getting a white screen when the application is opened in IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7

Sometimes I'm getting a white screen when the application is opened. I also killed the app in the task manager and opened it. But when i saw the console the "applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method is running as i have included some logs to confirm it. Not getting any crashes. None of the http requests are done in main thread. Though there are core data insertion for which i have used "Core data concurrency" so it will be running in a separate queue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And right now i'm testing the app through ad-hoc distribution

Comment: Please share your code so it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: When this happens, you can use Xcode's "pause" button to drop into the debugger and see what's going on in the app. This is often useful when the app is not responding and you don't know why.

Comment: @TomHarrington I'm downloading the application and testing. In the log i cannot see any warning or errors when this happens. And also the display name of the application also is changed when i get the white screen. Any idea about this ?

Comment: @GadMarkovits code is pretty big. So i have mentioned what all i'm doing. A http request using dispatch and also core data operations are done in a separate queue. None of this are done in main thread

Comment: @Avinash, have you tried what I suggested? It's the first thing I would do.

Comment: @TomHarrington yes i could not see anything wrong. The functionality is working. But the UI is not.

Comment: The question suggests that something is blocking the main thread. However, there's nowhere near enough detail here to work out what that is. You'll need to look into what's happening on the main thread when the app starts up (probably starting with `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`). Step through the code in the debugger and see what's up.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below it should work

```
[self.window setRootViewController:youFirstView];
```